# Образование: продолжать или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

Всем привет, друзья.

Сейчас у меня следующая ситуация:
Я учусь на комерческом отделении в местном ВУЗе, а точнее Энерго университете города Иваново или ИГЭУ им. Ленина, I курс.
Факультет: `Информатики и Вычислительной Техники.`
Направление: `Разработка программно-информационных систем.`
Оплата: 58к за семестр. Не мало так.

Расскажу об обстановке:
Нас учили С++. Доучили до структур и списков, еще затронули рекурсию. Никакого ООП. Даже не разрешали, если кто-то умел. Я как то сделал программу с вектором, так потом пришлось переделывать. Со следующего семестра мы начинаем изучать C#. По программированию всегда у меня стоят пятерки, все сдаю раньше всех, а в первом семестре даже поставили автомат. Все дело в том, что программирование я изучал лет с 14, знаю PHP вдоль и поперек, знаю не плохо JS, и смогу его применить при нужном случае, вот С++ изучил уже прилично, обгоняя своих однокурсников в разы, ну и в добавок прочитал и изучил синтаксис Swift по офф книжкe от Apple буквально за 1 день.

Что касается остальных предметов, таких как мат анализ, то могу сказать что все что я от туда вынес, это то, как пользоваться сайтом Wolfram|Alpha Pro. И так практически по всем предметам, я в них остался нулем. Но тем не менее все в силах сдать. Каким образом - не знаю, чаще всего списываю.

А теперь к проблеме:
Завтра меня должны отчислить, за неуплату. Я не принес денег за II семестр. У меня их попросту нет.
Сейчас я обращаюсь к очень опытным программистам, которые прочувствовали уже весь рынок.
Я могу сейчас пойти и взять эти в долг, что бы продолжить учиться. Мало того, я даже эти деньги и отдам, будет тяжело, но отдам. Да и не важно это. Скажите мне, насколько важно сейчас программисту в России иметь высшее образование? Я даже разделю этот вопрос на несколько частей, учитывая обстановку в стране:

1. На сколько сильно мне потребуются эти "универсальные" знания в будущем?
2. Какого программиста из меня сделают, и сделают ли вообще?
3. На сколько важны сейчас "корки" при приеме на работу?
4. Смогу ли я, как и раньше, продолжить обучение самостоятельно дома? И на сколько это будет эффективно?
5. На что сейчас смотрят в первую очередь при приеме на работу (даже на пристежную работу с хорошей зарплатой): на "корки", знания или опыт?

Спасибо всем кто прочитал, и еще большее тем, кто ответит.

P.S. в армию годен, категория "Б"

Comment: Эх. Мне из Мюнхена, конечно, сложно рассудить. Но мне кажется, что высшее образование надо получить, это инвестиция в самого себя. Другое дело, хороший ли у вас вуз. Может быть, можно совместить с подработкой? ЗЫ: Вопрос не вписывается в новый формат, так что его может быть удалят. Если что, заходите в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Comment: @VladD совсем забыл, что я больше не на хешкоде:(

Comment: Хешкод теперь здесь, темп другой, всё другое.

Comment: @VladD совмещать не получается, я пытаюсь учиться, и делать что то кроме программирования, но даже при таком раскладе у меня мало что получается. Но хотя бы держусь на плаву.

Comment: Универсальные знания в будущем пригодятся, вопрос в том, получите ли вы эти знания по-другому. Может и правда хорошей идеей было бы совместить учёбу и подработку? Заодно (1) плюс практика программирования, (2) плюс деньги.

Comment: Может, взять академотпуск, и немного подзаработать?

Comment: @VladD была такая идея, но сначала я должен доучиться эту сессию, да и ще и все сдать. А отчисляют уже завтра. Только если восстанавливаться через год, и то, что я уже сдал мне еще раз сдавать не придется же.

Comment: Ну, возможно споит напрячься, чтобы досдать сессию. А там за лето будет видно. Но подождём, может у кого-то ещё будут умные мысли.

Comment: Да, если вы соберётесь работать в Европе, высшее техническое образование тут практически необходимость.

Comment: По пунктам: 1) лишних знаний не бывает 2) не знаю, но подозреваю, что нет, если сами глубоко копать не станете 3) не слишком, но все меняется, похоже скоро очень даже понадобятся 4) сможете и это (imho) будет самым эффективным 5) знания, сообразительность и опыт важны для непосредственого босса, а для кадровика (это в больших конторах) важны корки (причем, какая там специальность -- пофиг, ну, конечно, желательно что бы  не гуманитарная). / Резюме -- получить корки все же важно. А в бесплатный хороший ВУЗ поступить сейчас нереально?

Comment: У меня два диплома, профильный - только переподготовка, не спрашивали никогда; специальность - веб-разработка.

Comment: А вариант с поступлением на бюджет, подработкой? Факт в том что позже будет сложно опять найти время на получение "официального" образования. Так то конечно все равно самообразование.

Answer (score 2):

Если вкратце, то без корочек ты обречен на судьбу эникейщика у безвестного ИП/ЧП. На пиво конечно заработаешь, но увы на икорку не хватит.

Корочки нужны. Если по пунктам, то:

1. Дело не в универсальных знаниях, а в порядке их преподавания. Как бы их хреново бы не преподавали, но методики обучения придумывают люди неглупые и в итоге знания ложатся в башку правильно. А правильно не значит запомнить, а значит вспомнить их нужное время и в нужном месте. К слову сказать правильно вам не дают писать на плюсах, а дрочат на классическом Си :)
2. Программиста из вас они не сделают. Дадут только необходимые базовые знания и не более того. Программистом можно стать только самому
3. Да это важно. Если собираетесь всю жизнь вести учет пива в придорожном кафе - то корочки не нужны. Если претендуете на что-то более духоподъемное - то без корочек никуда.
4. Конечно можете, но базовые знания дает таки ВУЗ. В противном случае без системных знаний будет тяжело.
5. Для стартовой позиции важны корочки. С годами и опытом значение корочки падает.

Comment: Увы, но и после института на икорку тоже не хватит. Здесь в IT выигрывает тот, у кого больше опыта(да, я полностью согласен только с 5 пунктом - остальное же, простите, красивое языкознание, на мой взгляд). Выпускник института здесь всегда проигрывает по сравнению с человеком, который в целевой сфере работал. Единственное - разница в самоуверенности, у выпускника она обычно загнанна до небес(я "пять лет мучался же!"), но это не умоляет часто полного отсутствия опыта и даже минимального багажа полезных навыков.

Answer (score 0):

Никуда не поступай :) Лучше сам читай книжки :) Думаю, что так ты больше и быстрее получишь знания. Читай, читай, читай :)
Кто то дал прогноз, что в скором будущем будет тотальная не хватка программистов. Помню цифры, что нужно будет 1,500,000 программистов, а нехватка будет 700,000. Вроде такие цифры. :)
У меня 9 классов образования и я не парюсь. Если ты программист, думаю, что им будет фиолетово где и как ты учился. Пнут только из-за не знаний.
А за будущую вакансию программиста не переживай :)
Кстати, тоже отчислен :)

Comment: Что может быть великолепней планирования жизни по "кто-то дал прогноз"

Comment: Нехватка программистов, положим, и так постоянная на рынке. **Хороших** программистов.

Answer (score 0):

1. Они бесполезны в абсолютном большинстве случаев.

   Пускай для кого-то это прозвучит обидно, однако в нашей стране ещё нет ни единого ВУЗа, обучаясь в котором программированию вы могли бы получить эквивалентный или больший объем полезных навыков, нежели непосредственно в процессе работы по специальности.

   Чего не скажешь о гуманитарных специальностях - им у нас обучают порой в разы лучше чем на западе.

   Хотите хорошее образование программиста? Тогда уезжайте учится в США, Чехию, Германию, Францию, или Канаду. Там это выгодно. Здесь же вы можете нормально обучится только в процессе работы.

   Высшее образование лучше тоже получить уже в процессе работы программистом. Хотя бы по прошествии пары-тройки лет. Причем желательно уже не связанное не с программированием, а с тем, в какой роли вы видите себя в будущем:  руководящие специальности, либо что-то по прикладным направлениям в которых вы уже в тот момент будете работать - экономика, логистика, юриспруденция, медицина, и т.д. - для более глубокого их понимания.
2. Крайне посредственного, если не найдете возможность постоянной практики на стороне.
3. В негосударственных компаниях у меня ни разу не спрашивали, и никогда не просили показать - даже при приеме на руководящие должности. )) Более того, со временем вообще убрал раздел "образование" из своего резюме. )

   В госкомпаниях диплом требуют практически всегда, однако и вакансии с достойными условиями у них попадаются крайне редко.
4. Всё зависит от вас. Но лучше - идите сразу на работу программиста. Мотивировать себя сидя дома не так уж и легко.
5. Уже писал в ответе на 3-й вопрос про это, однако повторюсь: при устройстве по IT-специальностям в России практически **никогда** не смотрят на диплом.

   Здесь в дипломы верят редко - большинство тоже учились, и прекрасно знают про коньяки-шоколадки на сессии, да про фрилансеров на дипломы ))

   В нормальных компаниях либо требуют выполнить практическое задание, либо просто сразу устраивают с испытательным сроком, да смотрят на ваши результаты по итогу этих двух-трех отработанных месяцев.

Comment: насчет "ни одного ВУЗв" наверное не соглашусь, но в целом да - уровень образования у нас плачевно низкий. Образованные люди стране к сожалению не нужны

Comment: Ну почти все вроде верно написано, за исключением одного - кандидата без корочек просто даже не допустят до интервью - наличие корочек это первый фильтр который проверяет кадровичка/HR - очевидно ТС имеет корочки и поэтому даже не знает, что есть такой фильтр ))

Comment: *в России практически никогда не смотрят на диплом*. Так-то оно так, но если в шортлист на вакансию попадет парень без диплома и выпускник  ИТМО или там матмеха СпбГУ - отгадайте, кого возьмут.

Comment: Могу сказать про доп образование в Питерском политехе, конечно если самому не интерисоваться то готовым специалистом вы не выйдете, но по факту получается хороший кругозор: структуры данных, алгоритмы, железо (vhdl и т.д.), языки по верхам. Отличная среда, чтобы самому заниматься и понимать направления для самообразования.

Comment: ЗЫ. Ничего не могу сказать про гуманитарные специальности, но физике и математике до сих пор хорошо учат.

Comment: Я не согласен с тем, что техническое образование в России хуже. Оно _ухудшается_, это да. Но по сравнению с Европой наш (хороший) студент выглядит не хуже, а обычно и лучше местного. У нас прекрасно умеют учить думать и учиться. Проблема в другом: не хватает _конкретных_ и _актуальных_ знаний, но это как раз устранимо чтением книжек.

Comment: @VladD, Полностью согласен, хотя я и говорил не про все технические специальности, а конкретно про IT-сферу. ) Думать у нас ещё могут научить, да. Но проблема актуальности и объема преподаваемых знаний в том-же программировании сейчас навряд-ли решаема - у нас, в отличии от западных коллег преподают вовсе не люди создававшие или участвующие в создании той или иной технологии. Типичный образ преподавателя - педагог по профессии, которому просто поручили научить людей какому-то модному веянию. И дальше на лекциях просто начинается чтение материала из книг и статей в интернете.

Comment: @Nofate,  Barmaley - в нормальных IT-компаниях такого "фильтра" не существует. Из двух людей - с дипломом и без - всегда выбирают того, кто лучше показывает свой опыт на практике.